# Reliable way to add "extra" NFTs to a collection post minting

Tags: metaplex, nft

Let's say I release a collection of 1000 NFTs and it minted out. Then suddenly the team decided to add 100 new rare NFTs but have it under the same collection.

What's the standard and reliable way in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about on chain collections (also called Metaplex Certified Collection or MCC):

You just add the NFTs to the collection. If you mint those without candy machine use metaboss https://metaboss.rs/collections.html#using-a-mint-list-file if you want to mint them with a candy machine create one without collection set (e.g. when using sugar use no collection.json), then run the collection set command https://docs.metaplex.com/tools/sugar/commands#collection

Comment: So having new NFTs in the collection just means adding more into the list?